# Convert integer to half-precision floating point format using round-to-even

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

I already know how to implement conversion to half-precision floating point using truncating (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12819124/10344534)). But how can I do the same conversion using rounding for nearest representable ? For example, i want 65519 to round to 0x7bff (which is 65504), not to infinity. One more example: in the linked solution 8199 will be represented by 8192, but the nearest representable for 8199 is 8200

**UPD:** For more example cases:  I want to round integers between 32768 and 65519 to a multiple of 32, integers between 16384 and 32768 round to a multiple of 16 and so on. In this solution 8199 will be represented by 8192, but the nearest representable for 8199 is 8200

Comment: 65519 is an integer. Round to what? Are you just setting the last *N* bits to zero?

Comment: @tadman This is half-precision floating point so OP must mean 65519.0 cannot be represented.

Comment: it cannot be represented. For example, i want to round integers between 32768 and 65519 to a multiple of 32, integers between 16384 and 32768 round to a multiple of 16 and so on. Looking for best way to implement this on c

Comment: @FiddlingBits That'd make more sense, sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two pieces to achieve what you want.

**1. add rounding before you do the conversion**

by adding:

```
  // round the number if necessary before we do the conversion
  if (manbits > 13)
    absx += (2<<(manbits-13));

  manbits = 0;
  tmp = absx;
  while (tmp)
  {
    tmp >>= 1;
    manbits++;
  }
```

before you do the conversion.

**2. Change the clipping to infinty to `> 16`**

by changing

```
  if (exp + truncated > 15)
```

to:

```
  if (exp + truncated > 16)
```

I updated the original code https://ideone.com/mWqgSP

Comment: but in this way other values will still be truncated, for example 8199 will be represented by 8192, but the nearest representable for 8199 is 8200

Comment: My edit should fix your issue. So down vote shouldn't be necessary anymore :) Unless I missed something else, please let me know.

Comment: it doesn't work correct for some test cases (for example 65539 should be represented by infinity). I want to implement precision limitations exactly like they are described on Wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Actually just read your title again, it mentions round-to-even. Now I understand what you want.

Comment: i want round-to-even, i think in this case it will be equal to round to nearest representable. Am i wrong?

Comment: I updated the code again. I think this time it should round-to-even

Comment: can value (manbits - 13) become negative in this implementation ? Can you explain why it's correct ?

Comment: there are still problems with representing some integers, trying to find suitable test cases for them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204498/discussion-between-hko-and-envy-grunt).