# Floating point convert method

Tags: c, types, floating-point

I tried to convert Unsigned 16 type floating point number but I couldn't find which functions or conversation method do I have to use for this.

For example I have 3 decimal numbers and these numbers have came with these hex value
BD97 >>>>>>>  38.84

3098 >>>>>>>  38.96

8497 >>>>>>>> 38.79

I belive these are half precision floating point but couldn't understand how can I convert them.
Is there any body help on this matter?

**Update** 
:

I'm sorry I think I couln't explain clearly. The values I wrote above comes from a kind of serial bus but these values also printed on display. Value from serial bus coming Unsigned16(I think this is special 16bit data type).

For example when I read 0xBD97 from bus, machine display shows 38.84
or when I read 0x3098, display shows 38.96.

The interesting thing is, these hex value which I get from bus seems irrelevant to the data shown on display. So, I thought this data was half precision data but I couldn't find how to convert it.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't see this? [Half-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Post actual code instead of trying to explain it.

Comment: "Is there any body help on this matter?" --> [Half-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format), else it looks like you are asking for a library or code dump - which is off topic.

Comment: "I tried to convert ..." --> post the code of that attempt.

Comment: "I tried to convert Unsigned 16 type floating point number..." Sorry but that is completely unclear. Unsigned 16 may be a `unsigned 16 bit integer` but a `floating point number` ? And what conversion are trying to do?

Comment: Maybe a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817410/convert-int-to-16bit-float-half-precision-floating-point-in-c

Comment: https://reviews.llvm.org/D4927#change-wgoYqk5rmvQf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data being read from the bus does not seem to use a floating-point format. Based on the two data items provided, it seems to be an integer scaled by a factor of 1000. We observe that `8497` = `0x9784` = 38788 → 38.79, and that `3098` = `0x9830` = 38960 → 38.96.