# How to convert IEEE 754 half-precision number to float and vice versa

Tags: c++

I am use the CCS compiler to microcontroller and I am taking a frame of reads from a RTU in hexadecimal of 2 bytes (16 bist) which I store in an int16 array, these stored data are floating point numbers in IEEE 754 half-precision representation, I need to perform arithmetic operations with these reads and the only one way to do them is to convert these numbers to float:

Example:

```
Number   float           IEEE 754 

A        12.50          0x4A40
B        11.75          0x49E0

A+B      24.25          0x4E10
```

if I did the operation as simple hexadecimal sums A + B = 0x4A40 + 0x49E0 = 0x9420 which is totally different from the value obtained if I work with its float representation 0x4E10, I need the conversion algorithms to port it to the compiler that I use

Comment: How are you storing a "base ten decimal number"?   Such a thing is not standard in C++.   So, effectively, you're asking for an algorithm to convert something that is unspecified to half-precision IEEE-754.

Comment: @Peter I'd assume that's just a really awkward way of saying `int`.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Maybe.   I've also seen the occasional question here about how to convert a base 10 decimal number to an `int`, or vice versa, so I wouldn't assume anything.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817410/convert-int-to-16bit-float-half-precision-floating-point-in-c

Comment: @Peter the question was edited, you were right to be skeptical.