# Converting Float32 to Float16

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, bit-manipulation, half-precision-float

This is more a follow up to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5587983/13586005. @sam hocevar or anybody else who understands this: Would you mind explaining what is happening here:

```
tmp = (tmp - 0x70) & ((unsigned int)((int)(0x70 - tmp) >> 4) >> 27);
```

I'm not sure I fully follow it. I understand that `(tmp - 0x70)` is correcting for the 127->15 bias, but I don't understand the 2nd part(`(unsigned int)((int)(0x70 - tmp) >> 4) >> 27`) and therefore don't understand the & with the corrected bias in the last step. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
(unsigned int)((int)(0x70 - tmp) >> 4) >> 27
```

is equivalent<sup>1</sup> to

```
(int)(0x70 - tmp) < 0 ? 0x1f : 0
```

but guarenteed to not involve a branch -- it instead extracts the sign bit from the result of the extraction, replicates it 4 times, then downshifts to get either 0x1f or 0 depending.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Under the assumption that signed right shifts of negative numbers do a proper arithmetic shift -- not guarenteed by the C spec, but common on most implementations</sub>