# Half-float conversion algorithm in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit to 16-bit Floating Point Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659440/32-bit-to-16-bit-floating-point-conversion)

How do I convert between 32-bit floats and 16-bit half-precision floats in C?

Comment: What is this type with 16-bit half-precision float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C typically doesn't have a 16-bit floating point type built-in, I would expect you would either have to

1. Use some super-specific platform "magic", like  a dedicated CPU instruction if available. This will of course not be a C solution, it will likely be inline assembly in the C source. Not portable.
2. Manually extract the required bits into perhaps an `unsigned short`. This will be portable, but might be a lot slower.

Both of these assume all you want to do is build the value's representation, you can't do arithmetic using C's operators of course.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you checking up this [half_floats](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23173)

You should also think about the way you will store these half-floats (there is no such type in C)