# How can I use swift 4 to write a portion of raw bits from an array of array of doubles?

Tags: swift, io, swift4

I have some code that currently uses NSArrays to save data to a file. The file size is too large for my needs so I wanted to be able to write an array of doubles to a file while possibly also pruning some of the insignificant bits.

```
var arr: [[Float]] = []
arr.append([Double(1.0), Double(2.0), Double(3.0)]
arr.append([Double(4.0), Double(5.0), Double(6.0)]

if let outputStream = OutputStream(url: getFileUrl(), append: true) {
    outputStream.open()
    for sub_array in arr {
         for item in sub_array {
             outputStream.write(one_quarter_of_bits(item))
         }
    }
    outputStream.close()
}
```

Above is the psuedo-code. It is an important design goal that the file be as small as possible including dropping some of the insignificant bits.

Comment: You can do that custom math, but you would have to implement it yourself. You can read the mantissa and exponent of the `Float`, round them to whatever makes sense for your application, and then combine them into a `Data` instance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to convert an array of Doubles (64-bit) to half-precisions (16-bit)? Then see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959278/convert-half-precision-float-bytes-to-float-in-swift

Comment: @alexander,  if i write an nsdata object to file, does it write the raw bits or a binary representation of the object. It seemes like the latter when i read the docs and from practice.  i want to write the smallest files possible.

Comment: It depends, what serialization format are you using, exactly?

Comment: @alexander was used nested nsmutablearrays of nsmutablearrays and using the write method. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1415134-write