# Copying to and from half-precision F16 allocation in android (renderscript)

Tags: android, floating-point, precision, allocation, renderscript

Also asked here with no luck (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Rh_L9Jv_S8Q)

I'm trying to figure out how to do half-precision using types like `half` and `half4`. The only problem seems to be getting the numbers from java to renderscript and back.

**The Java Code:**

```
private float[] input;
private float[] half_output;
private RenderScript mRS;
private ScriptC_mono mScript;
private final int dimen = 15;
...

//onCreate
input = new float[dimen * dimen * 3];      //later loaded from file 182.24 3.98 105.83 226.08 15.2 80.01...
half_output = new float[dimen * dimen * 3];
...

//function calling renderscript
mRS = RenderScript.create(this);
ScriptC_halfPrecision mScript = new ScriptC_halfPrecision(mRS);

Allocation input2 = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.F16(mRS), dimen * dimen * 3);
input2.copyFromUnchecked(input);            //copy float values to F16 allocation

Allocation halfIndex = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.F16(mRS), dimen * dimen);
Type.Builder half_output_type = new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.F16(mRS)).setX(dimen * dimen * 3);
Allocation output3 = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, half_output_type.create());

mScript.set_half_in(input2);
mScript.set_half_out(output3);
mScript.forEach_half_operation(halfIndex);

output3.copy1DRangeToUnchecked(0, dimen * dimen * 3, half_output);  //copy F16 allocation back to float array
```

**The Renderscript:**

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.android.rs.hellocompute)

rs_allocation half_in;
rs_allocation half_out;

half __attribute__((kernel)) half_operation(uint32_t x) {
    half4 out = rsGetElementAt_half4(half_in, x);

    out.x /= 2.0;
    out.y /= 2.0;
    out.z /= 2.0;
    out.w /= 2.0;

    rsSetElementAt_half4(half_out, out, x);
}
```

I also tried this instead of the last line shown in the Java code:

```
float temp_half[] = new float[1];
for (int i = 0; i < dimen * dimen * 3; ++i) {     //copy F16 allocation back to float array
    output3.copy1DRangeToUnchecked(i, 1, temp_half);
    half_output[i]=temp_half[0];
}
```

All the above code works perfectly for `float4` variables in the renderscript and `F32` allocations in the java.
This is obviously because there is no issue going from renderscript `float` to java `float`.
But trying to go from java `float` (since there is no java `half`) to renderscript `half` and back again is very difficult.
**Can anyone tell me how to do it?**

Both of the above versions of the java code result in seemingly random values in the `half_output` array.
They are obviously not random because they are the same values every time I run it, no matter what the operation in the `half_operation(uint32_t x)` function.
I've tried changing the   `out.x /= 2.0;` (and corresponding y,z,w code) to  `out.x /= 2000000.0;`   or   `out.x *= 2000000.0;`
and still the values that end up in the `half_output` array are the same every time I run it.

Using input of `182.24 3.98 105.83 226.08 15.2 80.01...`

Using this java

```
output3.copy1DRangeToUnchecked(0, dimen * dimen * 3, half_output);  //copy F16 allocation back to float array
```

The resulting half_output is `46657.44 27094.48 3891.45 965.1825 36223.44 14959.08...`

Using this java

```
float temp_half[] = new float[1];
for (int i = 0; i < dimen * dimen * 3; ++i) {     //copy F16 allocation back to float array
    output3.copy1DRangeToUnchecked(i, 1, temp_half);
    half_output[i]=temp_half[0];
}
```

The resulting half_output is `2.3476E-41 2.5546E-41 6.2047E-41 2.5407E-41 1.9802E-41 2.4914E-41...`

Again these are the results no matter what I change the   `out.x /= 2.0;`   algorithm to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this copy does not do a conversion. It will just put your source FP32 values into memory, but then when you try and interpret those values as FP16, they will be incorrect.

```
input2.copyFromUnchecked(input);            //copy float values to F16 allocation
```

You might port something like the answer from this question to renderscript:

[32-bit to 16-bit Floating Point Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659440/32-bit-to-16-bit-floating-point-conversion)

If your input doesn't have denorms/infinity/nan/overflow/underflow this seems like an ok solution:

```
uint32_t x = *((uint32_t*)&f);
uint16_t h = ((x>>16)&0x8000)|((((x&0x7f800000)-0x38000000)>>13)&0x7c00)|((x>>13)&0x03ff);
```

Really the solution is to have your source values in the file in fp16 binary format already. Read them into a java byte[] array and then do the copy into the fp16 input allocation. Then when the renderscript kernel interprets them as fp16 then you should have no problem.