# Declaring Half precision floating point memory in SYCL

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, sycl, intel-oneapi, half-precision-float

I would like to know and understand how can one declare half-precision buffers and pointers in SYCL namely in the following ways -

- Via the buffer class.
- Using malloc_device() function.

Also, suppose I have an existing fp32 matrix / array on the host side. How can  I copy it's contents to fp16 memory on the GPU side.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For half-precision, you can just use `sycl::half` as the template parameter for either of these.

```
accHalf[i] = static_cast<sycl::half>(accFloat[i]);
```

For copying, you'll need to convert the data from fp32 to fp16, which you could probably do using a kernel to perform the conversion. This seems to be a well documented problem with solutions, [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659440/32-bit-to-16-bit-floating-point-conversion).

Comment: Thanks Rod, This is helpful