# How to create a custom winrt::Microsoft::AI::MachineLearning::TensorFloat16Bit?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-machine-learning

How do I create a `TensorFloat16Bit` when manually doing a tensorization of the data?

We tensorized our data based on this Microsoft example, where we are converting 255-0 to 1-0, and changing the RGBA order.

```cpp
        ...
        std::vector<int64_t> shape = { 1, channels, height , width };
        float* pCPUTensor;
        uint32_t uCapacity;

        // The channels of image stored in buffer is in order of BGRA-BGRA-BGRA-BGRA. 
        // Then we transform it to the order of BBBBB....GGGGG....RRRR....AAAA(dropped) 
        TensorFloat tf = TensorFloat::Create(shape);
        com_ptr<ITensorNative> itn = tf.as<ITensorNative>();
        CHECK_HRESULT(itn->GetBuffer(reinterpret_cast<BYTE**>(&pCPUTensor), &uCapacity));

        // 2. Transform the data in buffer to a vector of float
        if (BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8 == pixelFormat)
        {
            for (UINT32 i = 0; i < size; i += 4)
            {
                // suppose the model expects BGR image.
                // index 0 is B, 1 is G, 2 is R, 3 is alpha(dropped).
                UINT32 pixelInd = i / 4;
                pCPUTensor[pixelInd] = (float)pData[i];
                pCPUTensor[(height * width) + pixelInd] = (float)pData[i + 1];
                pCPUTensor[(height * width * 2) + pixelInd] = (float)pData[i + 2];
            }
        }
```

ref: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/blob/2179a1dd5af24dff4cc2ec0fc4232b9bd3722721/Samples/CustomTensorization/CustomTensorization/TensorConvertor.cpp#L59-L77

I just converted our `.onnx` model to float16 to verify if that would provide some performance improvements on the inference when the available hardware provides support for float16. However, the binding is failing and the suggestion [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/performance-memory#float16-support) is to pass a `TensorFloat16Bit`.

So if I swap the TensorFloat for TensorFloat16Bit I get an access violation exception at `pCPUTensor[(height * width * 2) + pixelInd] = (float)pData[i + 2];`  because `pCPUTensor` is half of the size of what it was. It seems like I should be reinterpreting_cast to `uint16_t**` or something among those lines, so `pCPUTensor` will have the same size as when it was a TensorFloat, but then I get further errors that it can only be `uint8_t**` or `BYTE**`.

Any ideas on how I can modify this code so I can get a custom TensorFloat16Bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [factory methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ai.machinelearning.tensorfloat16bit.createfromarray?view=winrt-22621) on `TensorFloat16Bit`.

However, you will need to convert you data to `float16`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60047308/11998382

Also, I might recommend you instead do the conversion within the onnx model.

Comment: Thank you, that is what we ended up doing a couple weeks ago. I ran into the same stackoverflow post about this exact Float16 conversion. Our 32 bit implementation was using the `Create()` factory method so I used that instead. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AnnaMaule did you run into any performance issues? My performance on WinML is dreadful compared to pytorch...

Comment: yes, I ran the same model in pytorch/python framework and then after converting that model to .onnx and running inside the WinML, with GPU acceleration end-to-end, there was a significant performance hit and it was very disappointing to see such discrepancy between both frameworks.

Comment: @AnnaMaule it's the dynamic axis. Take them out and it's just as fast. Very disappointing. I made a [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/issues/513#issue-1567315863) about this

Comment: @AnnaMaule they've fixed it for the next release https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/14550

Comment: thank you so much for sharing your Github issues. I will give this a try and see how much this can improve the performance of the models I am looking at.

Comment: @AnnaMaule you don't have to re-export you models from pytorch. You can use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ai.machinelearning.learningmodelsessionoptions.overridenameddimension?view=winrt-22621) instead

Comment: sorry for the delay. I tried the api you mentioned and unfortunately that did not help with the performance improvements I was hoping to see.

Comment: I noticed you are using a python framework, while I am seeing a big discrepancy on the model inference between a python implementation versus a C++ .NET implementation. And the discrepancy is on the model inference performance.

Comment: I'm using c++ WinML, just used python to get profiling. The inference times where exactly the same for me

Comment: Maybe you're running one on the cpu and one on the gpu???

Comment: Maybe one's using an older onnxruntime version

Comment: No both ways are gpu accelerated. And we are using the latest onnxruntime version for the c++ implementation.